# Why we cannot delete function in javascript using delete operator?

Tags: javascript, delete-operator

```
var sum = function(a, b) {return a + b;};

var add = sum;

delete sum;
```

After Executing Delete it return False in console. Ideally it should return True.
Why **sum** function is not deleted?

Note above code is executed in google chrome browser console.

Answer (score 1):

[delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) cannot delete with direct member .

> The delete operator removes a property from an object.

Since you giving `sum` and not telling from which object you want to remove it.

What you looking for is

```
delete window.sum
```

Now it removes the `sum` from `window` object :)

[**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/34h0f1ty/)

[image]

Comment: Running those code in the browser console gives `false` though.

Comment: @YangShun Can you please share a screenshot ?

Comment: Running the code by pasting in the browser directly shows false: http://prnt.sc/erexsg

Comment: @YangShun hmm . I can see a true on top. Confused

Comment: Yup not sure why running in jsfiddle gives true. I'm confused as well haha

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

> The delete operator removes a given property from an object.
>
> If the property which you are trying to delete does not exist, delete will not have any effect and will return true.
>
> If a property with the same name exists on the object's prototype chain, then, after deletion, the object will use the property from the prototype chain (in other words, delete only has an effect on own properties).
>
> Any property declared with var cannot be deleted from the global scope or from a function's scope.
>
> As such, delete cannot delete any functions in the global scope (whether this is part from a function definition or a function expression).
>
> Functions which are part of an object (apart from the global scope) can be deleted with delete.

Hence `sum` which is a function attached to the global scope, cannot be deleted with delete.

Comment: @Aniketbonagir can you run my demo and share the result please ?

Comment: @Aniketbonagir: Don't confuse scope with binding. That variables in global scope is **also** added to the global object is a convenience. It does not mean that the global object is a scope. Scopes are not objects.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

- The delete operator removes a property from an object.
- Any property declared with var cannot be deleted from the global scope or from a function's scope.
- As such, delete cannot delete any functions in the global scope (whether this is part from a function definition or a function expression).
- Functions which are part of an object (apart from the global scope) can be deleted with delete.

Comment: Even if you remove var you cannot delete. You can execute the above code without var. It will still return false.